# Get an FLabel or image to move with keyboard

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to get this JLabel to move, I tried everything and every code, but it just won't work. It never seems to work, I had put `repaint()` everywhere that would make sense and also the movement code and it still doesn't seem to work in any way what so ever. I just didn't try to do it with an imported image, since it was also somewhat hard to find a good way to do it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Move extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Move frame = new Move();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Move() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);    


            JLabel label = new JLabel("");
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Move.class.getResource("/images/Untitled-2.png")));
            label.setBounds(192, 130, 87, 58);
            contentPane.add(label);

            label.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                        label.setLocation(label.getX(),label.getY()+1);
                        label.repaint();
                    }
                    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                        label.setLocation(label.getX(),label.getY()-1);
                        label.repaint();
                    }
                    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        label.setLocation(label.getX()+1,label.getY());
                        label.repaint();
                    }
                    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        label.setLocation(label.getX()-1,label.getY());
                        label.repaint();
                    }
                    label.repaint();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Attach a `KeyListener` to the `Move` instance itself, not to a `label` inside it, i.e. use simply the following:

   ```
   addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { ...
   ```
2. Remove those `label.repaint();` statements, which are redundant.
3. You have mixed up left and right movements. So fix this, too.

When putting it all together, the final part of the `Move()` constructor should look like this:

```
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY() + 1);
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                label.setLocation(label.getX(), label.getY() - 1);
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                label.setLocation(label.getX() - 1, label.getY());
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                label.setLocation(label.getX() + 1, label.getY());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `it just won't work.` - the reason it doesn't work is because KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus and the label doesn't have focus. This solution only works in the simple scenario. The better solution is to use `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.